# get average (row, col) cell given array values as weights?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I'm trying to get the average row/col position using the array values as the weights.
This seems to work, but just feels wrong:

```
a = numpy.random.ranf(size=(5,5))
normalized_a = a/numpy.nansum(a)

row_values = []
col_values = []
for row, col in numpy.ndindex(normalized_a.shape):
    weight = int(normalized_a[row, col] * 100)
    row_values.extend([row] * weight)
    col_values.extend([col] * weight)

print "average row:", sum(row_values)/float(len(row_values))
print "average col:", sum(col_values)/float(len(col_values))
```

Is there a more efficient way to do this in numpy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A basic insight to speed up your calculation is that, since when doing row (column) calculations, all items in a same column (row) get multiplied by the same value, it will be faster to add them together, then multiply the result by the row (column) number. If your array is `m x n`, that reduces the number of multiplications you have to do from `2 * m * n` to `m + n`. And since you are doing multiplications and additions, you can use `np.dot` to try to scratch the last bit of performance. Building on @mgilson's tests:

```
def new3(normlized_a):
    weights  = numpy.floor(normalized_a * 100)
    total_wt = np.sum(weights)
    rows, cols = weights.shape
    row_values = np.dot(weights.sum(axis=1), np.arange(rows)) / total_wt
    col_values = np.dot(weights.sum(axis=0), np.arange(cols)) / total_wt
    return row_values, col_values
```

And these are my results and timings:

```
(1.8352941176470587, 2.388235294117647)
(1.8352941176470587, 2.388235294117647)
(1.8352941176470587, 2.388235294117647)
(1.8352941176470587, 2.388235294117647)
timing!!!
2.59478258085
1.33357909978
1.0771122333
0.487124971828 #new3
```

Comment: Well done.  +1 from me -- Although, I must say, I'm a bit disappointed.  I thought my answer was pretty good until I saw this one ...

Comment: Seems this question only brings grief too respondents, for I am not very happy either: "Dear Santa, I've been a very good boy this year, please bring me a PC like @mgilson's, that runs twice as fast as mine..." ;-)

Comment: Mine's a linux machine courtesy of my employer :)

Answer (score 1):

These seem to be a bit better:

```
import numpy

a = numpy.random.ranf(size=(5,6))
normalized_a = a/numpy.nansum(a)

def original(a, normalized_a):
  row_values = []
  col_values = []
  for row, col in numpy.ndindex(normalized_a.shape):
    weight = int(normalized_a[row, col] * 100)
    row_values.extend([row] * weight)
    col_values.extend([col] * weight)

  return sum(row_values)/float(len(row_values)), sum(col_values)/float(len(col_values))


def new(a, normalized_a):
  weights = numpy.floor(normalized_a * 100)
  nx, ny = a.shape
  rows, columns = numpy.mgrid[:nx, :ny]
  row_values = numpy.sum(rows * weights)/numpy.sum(weights)
  col_values = numpy.sum(columns * weights)/numpy.sum(weights)
  return row_values, col_values


def new2(a, normalized_a):
  weights = numpy.floor(normalized_a * 100)
  nx, ny = a.shape
  rows, columns = numpy.ogrid[:nx, :ny]
  row_values = numpy.sum(rows * weights)/numpy.sum(weights)
  col_values = numpy.sum(columns * weights)/numpy.sum(weights)
  return row_values, col_values


print original(a, normalized_a)
print new(a, normalized_a)
print new2(a, normalized_a)


print "timing!!!"

import timeit
print timeit.timeit('original(a, normalized_a)', 'from __main__ import original, a, normalized_a', number=10000)
print timeit.timeit('new(a, normalized_a)', 'from __main__ import new, a, normalized_a', number=10000)
print timeit.timeit('new2(a, normalized_a)', 'from __main__ import new2, a, normalized_a', number=10000)
```

The results on my computer:

```
(1.8928571428571428, 2.630952380952381)
(1.8928571428571428, 2.6309523809523809)
(1.8928571428571428, 2.6309523809523809)
timing!!!
1.05751299858
0.64871096611
0.497050046921
```

I used some of numpy's index tricks to vectorize the computation.  I'm actually a little surprised that we didn't do better.  `np.ogrid` is only about twice as fast as the original on your test matrix.  `np.mgrid` falls somewhere in between.